# Как реализовать прерывание программы с клавиатуры Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая будет требовать у пользователя ввода, пока не будет введен корректный ввод, либо пока пользователь не прекратит программу с клавиатуры, то есть нажмет комбинацию клавиш Ctrl-Break или аналогичную ей.
Моя программа не прерывается с нажатием комбинаций клавиш. Что нужно исправит?

```
c = True
while c:
    try:
        a = input()
        a = check_password(a)
        if a == 'l':
            print('ok')
            break
        elif a == 'Bye-Bye':
            print(a)
            c = False
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Bye-Bye')
        c = False
```

Comment: а `Ctrl+C` не пробовали ?

Comment: Код не прерывается никаким сочетанием клавиш

Comment: у мея под Windows 10 по комбинации `Ctrl+C` прерывается.

Comment: У вас печатает 'Bye-Bye'?

Comment: да, результат продемонстрировал в ответе.